# jquery with countdown redirect stuck on zero

Tags: jquery, redirect

Trying to redirect a page to another domain using jquery. I noticed if I try with other urls it redirects but doesn't redirect with the particular url I want to redirect to. Also noticed the link works if I click on it before the countdown gets to zero but doesn't work when the countdown is zero. Here are my html and jquery codes

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Redirect Site</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
           var delay = 10 ; 
           var url = "http://www.wordoflifedubuque.org"; 

           function countdown() { 
               setTimeout(countdown, 1000) ; 
               $('#countmesg').html("Redirecting in "  + delay  + " seconds."); 
               delay --; 
               if (delay < 0 ) { 
               window.location = url ; 
               delay = 0 ; 
          } 
        } countdown() ; 
    });      


    </script>

    <style>
        #countmesg{
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        .header{background-color: black;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 header">
           <img src="logo.png" class="res">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
               <h3>This website has moved, click the link <a href="http://www.wordoflifedubuque.org">http://wordoflifedubuque.org</a> to go to the new site or be redirected automatically.</h3>
                <div id="countmesg"></div>
           </div>
    </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow your workflow, it actually does work. The problem is that it doesn't stop working.  Once it reaches a number lower than 0, it continues to loop, so the timeout never stops.  This could be causing the issues, so try canceling the timeout when you redirect:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
       var delay = 10 ; 
       var url = "http://www.wordoflifedubuque.org"; 
       var timer=null
       function countdown() { 
           timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000) ; 
           $('#countmesg').html("Redirecting in "  + delay  + " seconds."); 
           delay --; 
           if (delay < 0 ) { 
               clearTimeout(timer);
               window.location = url ; 
               delay = 0 ; 
           } 
       } 
       countdown() ; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You continue to loop after the 10 seconds as up as you are loading another call to `countdown` on the event loop BEFORE you check the `delay` try checking after. Also the site doesn't have "www"

```
       function countdown() { 
           $('#countmesg').html("Redirecting in "  + delay  + " seconds."); 
           delay --; 
           if (delay < 0 ) { 
             window.location = url ; 
             delay = 0 ;
             return; // don't wait again 
          } 

          setTimeout(countdown, 1000) ; 
    } countdown() ;
```

Comment: Your code is still doing the same thing as before, the page gets stuck when countdown is at zero.

Comment: Notice the `return` statement, the `setTimeout` can't run any more if the delay is below zero.